# matlab 2009 creating symbol

Tags: matlab

how can i create symbolic variables in matlab 2009?
because it doesn't work for "sym" o "syms" command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need the [symbolic toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/) installed. If you have that installed, [this](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/Matlab/symbolic_math.html) document provides an introduction to working with it.

To see if you have the toolbox installed, just try one of the examples:

```
>> sqrt(sym(2))
```

You should get:

```
ans = 2^(1/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use 32bits MATLAB 2009a even your OS is 64 bits.
32bits MATLAB works perfectly in 64 bits OS line win 7 and win 8.1.
Even MATLAB 2007 works well for symbolic math commands.
Do not use CD autorun, go to folder win32 and click setup.